# Angular Update Guide from 5.0 to 6.0

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular5, angular6

According to [**this guide**](https://update.angular.io/), I have run `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json`. It shows below error. I have done all previous steps without an issue. Any clue?

***Note:*** I have removed `node_modules` folder and run `npm i` . But no luck yet.

```
>rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
Running the automatic migrations. Please, be patient and wait until the execution completes.
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lokuge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rxjs-tslint\node_modules\tslint\lib\linter.js:22:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
child_process.js:644
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: "C:\Users\lokuge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rxjs-tslint\node_modules\.bin\tslint" -c "C:\Users\lokuge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rxjs-tslint\rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.json" -p "src/tsconfig.app.json" --fix
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lokuge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rxjs-tslint\node_modules\tslint\lib\linter.js:22:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:601:13)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:641:13)
    at migrate (C:\Users\lokuge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rxjs-tslint\rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.js:18:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lokuge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rxjs-tslint\rxjs-5-to-6-migrate.js:25:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution.

`npm install -g typescript`

Comment: Are you sure you had to install typescript globally? Isn't `npm i typescript` enough?

Comment: @ochs.tobi Yes, It showed this at the end. `C:\Users\lokuge\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsserver -> C:\Users\lokuge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
C:\Users\lokuge\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\lokuge\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
+ typescript@2.9.2
added 1 package in 3.361s`